# Update WindowsAzure SDK references

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-sdk-.net

Is there a tool, or way to update your VisualStudio reference versions when a new version of the Azure SDK is installed?

Things like Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.dll and Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll are referenced by the folder

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Azure\.NET SDK\v2.8\ref\Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime.dll
```

rather than a nuget package (which would be auto updated when the nuget reference is updated). I noticed after cloning a repo to a machine with only v2.9 installed that my solution wouldn't build as there was a hard dependancy to an SDK version.

Comment: Normally when you upgrade the Cloud Services project via Visual Studio, all the references are upgraded automatically. Are you not seeing this behavior?

Comment: @Tim, did you resolve your problem? As Gaurav mentioned, they should be upgraded automatically - if not, there should be the menu in the project properties to upgrade the project.

Comment: No in this scenario its webjobs and they don't auto upgrade it seems @GauravMantri